# When to use Metal instead of Accelerate API on Apple macOs

Tags: macos, audio, signal-processing, core-audio

I'm currently writing a desktop audio processing application. Its purpose is to do a lot of signal processing so I'm really concerned about the performance and reliability.

I've already use the Audio toolbox / Core Audio APIs but for the custom audio processing I was wondering what will be the best fit between Metal and Accelerate. Anyone know about their difference? Or have benchmark? I didn't find something really useful with Google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metal shaders use the GPU.  Accelerate APIs use the CPU.  So it really depends on what kind of GPU the system you are using provides, and whether your custom processing kernels can use the GPU efficiently.  Examples might include algorithms that are massively parallel, such as convolution of large 2D arrays of data (much larger than 1D real-time audio buffers).

Comment: Thank you @hotpow2 . So if I understood well, I should look at [List of Mac computers that support Metal](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205073) (I put the link for reference for the readers) and I should also test if it's a real gain for "small" data size. I guess it's caused by the time transfer no?

Comment: A GPU processor core typically runs at clock rate that is much slower than the computer's main CPU, which means that a task with little parallelism would not benefit.  And divvying up data into smaller parallelizable chunks runs into the bad side of Amdahl's law.